# admob cpc is very low in 2017? how to solve?

Tags: android, admob, keyword, adsense

my admob cpc is very low only 0.02.my page view is 150000.page impression 70000 click 986.page rpm 17.

then.

*How to increase my cpc?

*If I BLOCK LOW CPC ADSENSE ADVERTISERS URL  then face any problem with admob?

please help.
advance thanks

Comment: Same here. My ecpm drops to 0.18. Used to be 0.22. Can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: I pass from 0.12 to 0.03 that is ridiculous !!

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?

Comment: has anyone solved the issue?